# Why the value is not decreasing after the timer is over?

Tags: java, android, mobile

**CONTEXT**
I have a simple app tracking the alcohol level in blood.

**GOAL**
Once the timer is over, I want to decrease the variable `alcoholLevel` by 0.15, using the function `decreaseAlcoholLevel`.

**PROBLEM**
It seems there are two variables `alcoholLevel`: one always decreasing (when the timer is over), and one always increasing (when i run `setNewAlcoholLevel`).

**CODE**

```
public class AlcoholLevel {
    public static TextView riskTxt;
    Integer weight, alcoholQty;
    double alcoholLevel;
    String gender;
    boolean ateRecently;
    double combinedWeight;
    protected static final DecimalFormat decfor = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    public AlcoholLevel(Integer weight, String gender, boolean ateRecently, TextView riskTxt) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.ateRecently = ateRecently;
        this.riskTxt = riskTxt;
    }


      //return formula alcohol level
    public void setNewAlcoholLevel(String drink) {
      
        //calculate formula
        double newAlcoholLevel = (alcoholQty * 0.008 * 1.055)/(weight * combinedWeight ) ;
        alcoholLevel += newAlcoholLevel;
        riskTxt.setText( decfor.format(alcoholLevel));
    }

    // Add the decreaseAlcoholLevel method to decrease the alcohol level
    protected void decreaseAlcoholLevel(double amount) {
        alcoholLevel -= amount;
        riskTxt.setText( decfor.format(alcoholLevel));
    }
```

```
public class TimedAlcoholLevel extends AlcoholLevel {
    private TextView clockTxt;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

    public TimedAlcoholLevel(Integer weight, String gender, boolean ateRecently, TextView clockTxt, TextView riskTxt) {
        super(weight, gender, ateRecently, riskTxt);
        this.clockTxt = clockTxt;
    }

    public void startTimer(){
        if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
            mCountDownTimer.cancel(); // cancel the previously started timer
        }
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // Used for formatting digit to be in 2 digits only
                NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("00");
                long hour = (millisUntilFinished / 3600000) % 24;
                long min = (millisUntilFinished / 60000) % 60;
                long sec = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                clockTxt.setText(f.format(hour) + ":" + f.format(min) + ":" + f.format(sec));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                decreaseAlcoholLevel(0.15);
                clockTxt.setText("00:00:00");
            }
        }.start();
    }


}
```

I tried to decrease the variable `alcoholLevel` in different ways, but it is not decreasing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it seems like there are two variables'?  You have one object, correct?  Therefore it has one alcoholLevel field.

Comment: THis is really poorly designed code.  Your model, your view layer, and your business logic are all mixed together.  Separate your concerns and you'll have an easier time debugging things.